# Is it possible to upload bulk In app purchase with Alternate Tier B as price from Application loader

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to upload bulk IAP using Application loader, having problem with Price tier "Alternate Tier B". 1-87 price tier working fine in application loader.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number code for each alternate tier.  The only reliable way to find the code that I have found is to create a dummy in app using Application Loader, to save the package and inspect it.

Alternate Tier B is 530 / 
Alternate Tier 1 is 550 /
Alternate Tier 2 is 560 /
Alternate Tier 3 is 570 /
Alternate Tier 4 is 580 /
Alternate Tier 5 is 590